# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class - spark/scala

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark/scala development. I am using maven to build my project and IDE is intelliJ. I am trying to query a hive table and then iterate over the resulting dataframe(using `foreach`). Here's my code:

```
try{
    val DF_1 = hiveContext.sql("select distinct(address) from 
     test_table where trim(address)!=''")
    println("number of rows: "+DF_1.count)
    DF_1.foreach(x => {
      val y =hiveContext.sql("select place from test_table where address='"+x(0).toString+"'")
      if(y.count > 1){
        println("Multiple place values for address: "+x(0).toString)
        y.foreach(r => println(r))
        println("*************")
      }
    })} 
catch {case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace()}
```

With each iteration, I am Querying the same table to get another column, trying to see if there are multiple values of `places` for each `address` in `test_table`. I have no compilation errors and the application builds successfully. But, when I run the above code, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class xxxxxxxx
```

the application launches successfully, prints the `count` of rows in `DF_1` and then fails with the above error at the `foreach` loop. I did a jar xvf on my jar and can see the main class - `driver.class`:

```
com/.../driver$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$1.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$2.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$3.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$4.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$5.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$2.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$3.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$1.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$10$$anonfun$apply$9.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$10.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$11.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$12.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$13.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$14.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$15.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$16.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$17.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$18.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$19.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$2$$anonfun$apply$4.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$2$$anonfun$apply$5.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$2$$anonfun$apply$6.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$2.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$20.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$21.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$22.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$23.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$3$$anonfun$apply$7.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$3$$anonfun$apply$8.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$3.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$4$$anonfun$apply$9.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$4.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$5.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$6$$anonfun$apply$1.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$6$$anonfun$apply$2.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$6$$anonfun$apply$3.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$6$$anonfun$apply$4.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$6$$anonfun$apply$5.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$6.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$7$$anonfun$apply$1.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$7$$anonfun$apply$2.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$7$$anonfun$apply$3.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$7$$anonfun$apply$4.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$7$$anonfun$apply$5.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$7$$anonfun$apply$6.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$7$$anonfun$apply$7.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$7$$anonfun$apply$8.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$7.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$8$$anonfun$apply$10.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$8$$anonfun$apply$4.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$8$$anonfun$apply$5.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$8$$anonfun$apply$6.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$8$$anonfun$apply$7.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$8$$anonfun$apply$8.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$8$$anonfun$apply$9.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$8.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$9$$anonfun$apply$11.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$9$$anonfun$apply$7.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$9$$anonfun$apply$8.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$9$$anonfun$apply$9.class
com/.../driver$$anonfun$main$9.class
com/.../driver$.class
com/.../driver.class
```

I am not facing the error when I launch the job in `local` mode instead of `yarn`. What is causing the issue and how can it be corrected?

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your your jar or some dependencies aren't distributed between worker nodes. In `local` mode it works because you have the jars in the place. In `yarn` mode you need to build a fat-jar with all dependencies include hive and spark libraries in it.

Comment: I’ve already built a fat jar. That’s the one I’m trying to run on the cluster. And I’m only having this issue with this piece of code. I’ve had no issues when I used the same Pom.xml for other applications. I’m guessing there is a piece of code in there that’s causing the issue.

Comment: Which class it cannot initialize? Your driver.class?

Comment: Yes. That’s my main class. What’s interesting is that it runs for a while and prints the count of rows in the dataframe before failing with the error.